# PHP echoing an amended list from database

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to make a script so dates added by form to a mysql database are checked against a list of dates between a start date and an end date. If the dates conflict they will be removed from the start date to end date list leaving no conflicts. This is what I have so far:

`

```
$date1 = '10/06/2014';
$date2 = '30/06/2014';

function returnDates($fromdate, $todate) {
 $fromdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fromdate);
    $todate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $todate);
    return new \DatePeriod(
  $fromdate,
  new \DateInterval('P1D'),
  $todate->modify('+1 day')
);
}

$datePeriod = returnDates($date1, $date2);
foreach($datePeriod as $date) {
     $possible=$date->format('dmY');
}`
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $dateday = $row['Day'];
  $datemonth = $row['Month'];
  $dateyear = $row['Year'];

  if($datemonth<"12"){
  $newmonthdate=("0$datemonth");
  }else{
  $newmonthdate=("$datemonth");
   }

   $taken="$dateday$newmonthdate$dateyear";
}

    if( $taken=$possible){
echo $taken;
```

the last bit is the part I'm stuck on, getting it to print out a the list of dates from the start date to the end date which don't contain the dates from the mysql database. At the moment I have the dates in the format of 23062014. (New to this so I feel I have made this more complicated than it needs to be) Thanks if you can help

Comment: Firstly, why aren't you using timestamps, and second can you rephrase your question, to me it's not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Wanting to create an event scheduler so a basic page where a user can add events to a database and then select a certain time frame , from Date 1 to Date 2 then for it to show all the available dates from Date 1 to Date 2 which don't clash with the dates entered into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can start by having an array of the possible dates, like this:

```
$datePeriod = returnDates($date1, $date2);
foreach($datePeriod as $date) {
     $possible[] = $date->format('dmY');
}
```

And in your while loop:

```
$taken = "$dateday$newmonthdate$dateyear";
array_remove($possible, $taken);
```

After your while loop you can just loop through the $possible array, which now contains only available dates.

The array_remove function is as follows:

```
function array_remove(&$source, $value) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($source as $s_value) {
        if ($s_value != $value) {
            $result[] = $s_value;
        }
    }

    $source = $result;
}
```